# In the equivalent circuit of transformer is the shut branch placed before or after the winding impedances in the primary?

Tags: transformer

I read a couple of books on transformers. A few have drawn the equivalent circuit with the shut branch placed before winding impedance while opposite was done in others. Which one is right?

Comment: if both are equivalent to transformers both are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shunt" branch (as I believe you are referring to) represents, amongst other things, the magnetization impedance as depicted by the impedance \$X_M\$ as shown below.

[image]

That branch is sometimes (in books etc.) shown across the far left terminals and this makes it easier to do the math when dealing with problems. However, there is a sacrifice made in doing so because it then doesn't fully represent the leakages (typified by \$X_P\$ etc.) and can lead to some errors.

My preference is to leave it exactly where it should be as indicated above.

Comment: Can this equivalent circuit used for any size of transformer? Power to audio?

Comment: @user164567 generally yes but, the higher in frequency yo go the more you stumble into problems from parasitic capacitance and have to add "features" to the above circuit. Usually audio isn't a problem though, even 20 kHz.